# I am trying to build a msbuild project for xbuild but it keeps failing

Tags: linux, vb.net, msbuild, travis-ci, xbuild

I have a [vb.net project](http://github.com/RX14/SWRChart/) that i would like to build using travis ci but travis only runs on linux so I have to use xbuild. I have the build log here. Can anybody tell me why the build is failing with this error?

```
Error executing tool '/usr/bin/vbnc': ApplicationName='/usr/bin/vbnc', CommandLine='/noconfig @/tmp/tmp3b9f993d.tmp', CurrentDirectory='/home/travis/build/RX14/SWRChart/src'
```

The full build log is available [here](https://travis-ci.org/RX14/SWRChart/builds/15493297) and the source is available [here](http://github.com/RX14/SWRChart/)

Answer (score 0):

It Seems that mono doesn't seem to support WPF so this is pointless. Oops.

Comment: Mono does not support a lot, not only WPF. However, it does support a lot that .NET Framework is not (such as GTK, Qt, Cocoa and so on). http://go-mono.com/status/